# CLR Can't find a type, even though it's in the same assembly

Tags: system.diagnostics, tracelistener

I'm troubleshooting a WCF problem in our application, and turned on WCF tracing with the WCF Service Configuration Editor in VS 2010, which added the following sharedListener to the web.config:

```
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="D:\Logs\CRCCustomerService\Web_tracelog.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
```

Now, when I take steps to reproduce my error, I'm getting an exception thrown from the System.Diagostics library saying that it can't find XmlWriterTraceListener:

```
Stack Trace: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for       'System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility' threw an exception. --->   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Couldn't find type for class System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089. 
at System.Diagnostics.TraceUtils.GetRuntimeObject(String className, Type baseType,    String initializeData) 
at System.Diagnostics.TypedElement.BaseGetRuntimeObject() 
at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() 
at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElement.GetRuntimeObject() 
at System.Diagnostics.ListenerElementsCollection.GetRuntimeObject() 
at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize() 
at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.get_Listeners()
```

And it goes on for several more lines, but this establishes the context.

My question is, since, according to ObjectBrowser and Reflector, XmlWriterTraceListener is a member class of the same assembly that System.Diagnostics is, how can it NOT not be able to find it?

And secondly, since every single line in the exception stack comes from system code, how on earth do I begin to debug the root cause here?

Comment: Have you tried removing all the assembly information and just leaving this type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .NET 4.0?

If not, you have to beware the service config utility.  It will hard code the version of the listener to 4.0 and you'll need to manually change your web.config